# Setting a dynamic domain (min and max axis) in Vega-Lite (Deneb)

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

Another week, another Vega-lite question I´m turning to you guys.
It´s actually pretty easy to create KPI cards in Deneb however what´s causing me headache is the positioning of marks.

As you can see on the picture below when the delta is positive it´s pushing the line to the top and when negative then to the bottom of the visual. I´ve tried to set fixed axis which solved my problem however it was not right because you have KPIs where the delta range differs most of the time. So I can´t put a range [-15%,15%] because at KPIs where range is between [-2%,2%] it´s creating a flat line basically. And I don´t want to set axis KPI by KPI separately.

Not even talking about when adding a text label to the visual it can be pushed out from the picture.

Do you have any idea of a workaround that could solve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

[image: Positive delta vs Negative delta]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The domain can be calculated dynamically as +/- 10% from your data. e.g. this example with no fixing.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 1, "y": 10},
      {"x": 2, "y": 10},
      {"x": 3, "y": 10},
      {"x": 4, "y": 10},
      {"x": 5, "y": 10},
      {"x": 6, "y": 10},
      {"x": 7, "y": 10}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "line", "point": true},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

Here it is scaled dynamically.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 1, "y": 10},
      {"x": 2, "y": 10},
      {"x": 3, "y": 10},
      {"x": 4, "y": 10},
      {"x": 5, "y": 10},
      {"x": 6, "y": 10},
      {"x": 7, "y": 10}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {"op": "max", "field": "y", "as": "max"},
        {"op": "min", "field": "y", "as": "min"}
      ]
    },
    {"calculate": "datum.max * 1.2", "as": "max"},
    {"calculate": "datum.min * 0.8", "as": "min"}
  ],
  "params": [
    {"name": "max", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['max']"},
    {"name": "min", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['min']"}
  ],
  "mark": {"type": "line", "point": true},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {
      "field": "y",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[min,max]"}}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can´t thank you enough!
You always deliver, it looks good finally!
Only adjustment I made was that I removed the calculate bc it messed up the the minimum on the axis when the minimum value was negative..
Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here's a way to do it without `transform`:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 1, "y": 10},
      {"x": 2, "y": 10},
      {"x": 3, "y": 10},
      {"x": 4, "y": 10},
      {"x": 5, "y": 10},
      {"x": 6, "y": 10},
      {"x": 7, "y": 10}
    ]
  },
  "params": [
    {"name": "extents", "expr": "extent(pluck(data('source_0'), 'y'))"},
    {"name": "max", "expr": "extents[0] * 0.8"},
    {"name": "min", "expr": "extents[1] * 1.2"}
  ],
  "mark": {"type": "line", "point": true},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {
      "field": "y",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[min,max]"}}
    }
  }
}
```