# Clarification on setting a dynamic domain in Vega-lite (Deneb)

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

In reference to this post

[Setting a dynamic domain in Vega-Lite (Deneb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75456476/setting-a-dynamic-domain-in-vega-lite-deneb/)

I would like to understand expressions in the below lines of code

```
"params":   
[
{"name": "max", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['max']"},
{"name": "min", "expr": "data('data_0)[0]['min']"}
]
```

I tried to implement the same code and tried to make changes but it doesn't work. The y-axis doesn't get plotted.

[MaxRange and MinRange showing values as 'undefined'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtRGZ.png)

[Lines overlapped with Y -axis showing blank/null values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC18L.png)

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "title": "All Points",
  "transform": [
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {
          "op": "max",
          "field": "dollar_price",
          "as": "_max"
        },
        {
          "op": "min",
          "field": "dollar_price",
          "as": "_min"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "Max_Range",
      "expr": "data('dataset')[0]['_max']"
    },
    {
      "name": "Min_Range",
      "expr": "data('dataset')[0]['_min']"
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "dollar_price",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {
        "domain": {
          "expr": "[Min_Range,Max_Range]"
        }
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "country_name",
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": "line"},
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "point",
        "size": 20
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dy": -10
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "calculate": "format(datum.dollar_price,'.1f')",
          "as": "New_Text"
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "New_Text",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you supply a sample .pbix with the issue you're encountering?

Comment: @DavideBacci  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GJUuiOCWrLMlpdZK8GbvY5sSFAWlfizs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @DavideBacci  I got an error "No signal data was found in the Vega view. Please ensure that your specification has parsed correctly and is free of errors."

Comment: Copy and paste the code exactly as written - it works.

Comment: @DavideBacci thank you for your patience. It works however the y axis keep changing when i select individual countries in the filter. As per the data , the min is 0.80  and max 8.06. So whatever the country is selected this y-axis range should not change.

Comment: This is a different question to the original. VL is only aware of the data you send to it. Mark this one as solved and ask a new question.

Comment: Done. Ok, if that is the case my question was how do i understand the below expression

"params":   
[
{"name": "max", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['max']"},
{"name": "min", "expr": "data('data_0)[0]['min']"}
]

Comment: the expression is as follows: data() gets a dataset named data_0 which is created by VL under the covers. This is provided as an array. [0] gets the first row in that array. ['max'] gets the named column in that first row so you end up with a single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VL does various things with the original dataset. Try this instead:

> "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['_max']"

[image]

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "title": "All Points",
  "transform": [
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {
          "op": "max",
          "field": "dollar_price",
          "as": "_max"
        },
        {
          "op": "min",
          "field": "dollar_price",
          "as": "_min"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "Max_Range",
      "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['_max']"
    },
    {
      "name": "Min_Range",
      "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['_min']"
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "dollar_price",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {
        "domain": {
          "expr": "[Min_Range,Max_Range]"
        }
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "country_name",
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": "line"},
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "point",
        "size": 20
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dy": -10
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "calculate": "format(datum.dollar_price,'.1f')",
          "as": "New_Text"
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "New_Text",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```