assign the max value of a column to a param
I have a simple question, but I'm not able to figure out the syntax ...
I want to assign the max value of the field "val" to the variable maxVal
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"rowgroup": "I", "segment": "C", "val": 2000000},
      {"rowgroup": "I", "segment": "B", "val": 7000000},
      {"rowgroup": "II", "segment": "A", "val": 4000000},
      {"rowgroup": "II", "segment": "B", "val": 1000000},
      {"rowgroup": "II", "segment": "D", "val": 2000000}
    ]
  },
"params":[
{"name":"maxVal", ...}
]

}

Thank you very much.

Use the technique described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75456476/setting-a-dynamic-domain-min-and-max-axis-in-vega-lite-deneb/75456962#75456962

Hey @davidebacci, this means I have to create the max value first in  the dataset using a transform?

Ignore the comment above, as I just read Daniel's answer.

The answer to my question is here: Setting a dynamic domain (min and max axis) in Vega-Lite (Deneb)
There are two approaches:
    "transform": [
    {
    "joinaggregate": [
    {"op": "max", "field": "y", "as": "max"},
    {"op": "min", "field": "y", "as": "min"}
    ]
    },
    {"calculate": "datum.max * 1.2", "as": "max"},
    {"calculate": "datum.min * 0.8", "as": "min"}
    ],
    "params": [
    {"name": "max", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['max']"},
    {"name": "min", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['min']"}
    ]

and
  "params": [
    {"name": "extents", "expr": "extent(pluck(data('source_0'), 'y'))"},
    {"name": "max", "expr": "extents[0] * 0.8"},
    {"name": "min", "expr": "extents[1] * 1.2"}
  ],

Here I prefer the "direct" parameter solution, as I did not need the min/max values in the dataset.
